# Headers only on right side for all the pages

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

I have a latex code from my friend, in which the headers are placed based on odd and even pages. What I want is to have all the headers on right side. I tried variety of options and also on forums, unfortunately could not get the required answer. My code for header is

```
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrpage2}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\clearscrheadfoot

\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\ohead{\headmark}

\automark[chapter]{chapter}

\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{0cm}}

\bibliographystyle{alphadin}
```

I really looking for a solution for my thesis work. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please consider providing an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), i.e. a short document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. And I am just guessing that adding `\ehead{}` gives you what you want, but I can't test this because I don't have an MWE to play with.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you want the verso (left) headers to be blank? In that case, the top of the main text would be the same position left and right. That is easy to do. Or do you want NO header at left? That involves different geomtery left and right: Then the top of the main text would be in a different position left or right. That is hard to do.

Comment: The code you provided is pretty useless right now. Are you looking for `oneside` option for documentclass?

Comment: Apart from that, `scrpage2` is obsolete. You should use `scrlayer-scrpage` instead. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_Page_Headers_and_Footers#Customizing_with_scrlayer-scrpage

Comment: Hello all, thank you very much for your time. I have found solution by myself. Posted in answer what was the update I did

Answer (score 1):

There are some outdated class options in the code snippet in your answer. Replace them by the key-value-syntax to avoid the warnings and the switch to `version=first`. Do not use `pdftex`. With a newer KOMA-Script version you should not redefine `\chapterheadstartvskip` to change the space before chapter headings.

Package `scrpage2` is outdated since 2014. Its successor is package `scrlayer-scrpage`with a similar syntax.

Onesided document based on your code-snippets:

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    %a4paper,% <- default
    BCOR15mm,% <- syntax changed
    DIV=14,% <- syntax changed
    parskip=half,
    %twoside,
    openany,
    numbers=noenddot,
    bibliography=totoc,
    index=totoc,
    titlepage
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\automark{chapter}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
\ohead{\headmark}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1sp% no vertical space before chapter title
]{chapter}

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Twosided document:

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    %a4paper,% <- default
    BCOR15mm,% <- syntax changed
    DIV=14,% <- syntax changed
    parskip=half,
    twoside,
    openany,
    numbers=noenddot,
    bibliography=totoc,
    index=totoc,
    titlepage
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
\rohead{\headmark}% right side on odd pages
\rehead{\headmark}% right side on even pages

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1sp% no vertical space before chapter title
]{chapter}

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

The second example works also, if you comment `twoside` or set `twoside=false`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions. I have just removed 'twoside' argument from the document class and it worked

```
\documentclass[
    pdftex,         
    12pt,                   
    a4paper,                                
    BCOR15mm,               
    DIV14,                  
    parskip=half,           
    %twoside,           
    openany,                
    numbers=noenddot,       
    bibliography=totoc,     
    index=totoc,
    titlepage
]{scrreprt}
```

Comment: Please don't just provide a snippet of code, but a full MWE as suggested in the other comments. Also don't include an option in the code where the point was that it is no longer there, instead comment it out (with `%`), which I fixed in my edit.